# Float h2 and h4 left and right on the same line and same height

Tags: html, css

So I am simply trying to make this header, with `h2` text on the left and `h4` on the right, so on the same line and height, along with some padding, this is my code:

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
}

.nav {
  clear: both;
}

.nav {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <h2 class="alignleft">Left side</h2>
  <h4 class="alignright">RIGHT SIDE</h4>
</div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lo1vxtj6/2/), any help very appreciated:

Answer (score 1):

You only write the class name in the `class` attribute, don't prefix it with the dot, so your code should be :

```
<div class="nav">
    <h2 class="alignleft">Left side</h2>
    <h4 class="alignright">RIGHT SIDE</h4>
</div>
```

and add a line-height to the css :

```
.alignleft {
    float: left;
    line-height:25px;
}

.alignright {
    float: right;
    line-height:25px; /*or whatever px's you want*/
}

.nav {
    clear: both;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: oh yes sorry I mistyped, but the problem remains, because the right one gets pushed up, here's the new fiddle and edit: https://jsfiddle.net/Lo1vxtj6/2/

Comment: Add a line-height to the css

Comment: Or vertical-align: -5px;

Answer (score 0):

As @MrGeek mentioned, you should remove the prefix `.` on class name. Then just assign the same line height for both `h2` and `h4` element.

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
}

.nav {
  clear: both;
}

.nav {
  background-color: grey;
}

h2, h4 {
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <h2 class="alignleft">Left side</h2>
  <h4 class="alignright">RIGHT SIDE</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it seems to work on the fiddle, but it still needs some tweaking on my website, will check. thank you!

Comment: You can update your question if you can provide something else :)